# Application of Weyl's Theorem

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras

Recall that [Weyl's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_Lie_algebra) says that any finite dimensional representation of semi simple Lie algebra is completely reducible. I'm trying some examples to understand this theorem properly.

Since $\bf sl_2(\bf C)$ acts on $V=\bf C^2$ by matrix multiplication, $V$ is an $\bf sl_2$-module.

> Decompose $V \otimes V$ as $\bf sl_2$-module.

Since I've just learned about Weyl's theorem so please don't use any high machinery. Any idea or reference is appreciated.

Comment: It decomposes as the symmetric square and the exterior square. The exterior square is trivial and the symmetric square is irreducible.